# Pass in array using request module on node or cURL on terminal

Tags: arrays, postgresql, curl, sequelize.js

I am trying to pass in data to an end point to store on a table in a PostgreSQL database. I need to pass an array as part of the body, but have been unable to find a way to do so using either the request module or through cURL.

My approach using cURL

```
curl --data "userName=redixhumayun&user_id=1&polls_created_id[]=1&polls_created_id[]=2&voter_ids[]=[]" 127.0.0.1:3000/data
```

My approach using the request module

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  request.post({
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/data', 
    form: {
        userName: 'redixhumayun', 
        user_id: 2, 
        polls_created_id=2&polls_created_id=43
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        console.log(body);
        res.json(body);
    }
  })
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Not sure how to go about doing this.

I have defined polls_created_id in my User DB as `DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER)`

Comment: See this post for cURL params: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740053/posting-array-using-curl-in-terminal

Comment: Yeah, I tried that approach already. However, the data for my array always returns null. This is how I am trying to access it.

const polls_created_id = req.body.polls_created_id;

Comment: `--data voter_ids[]=foo --data voter_ids[]=bar --data voter_ids[]=baz --data voter_ids[]=zig --data voter_ids[]=zag`